# Submitting form twice JQuery and Php

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, joomla3.0

I have a long form that is accessed from frontend and backend in Joomla where there are selects and number / text inputs that I added which update DB fields "on the fly" using `data-input="some value"` and `value="some value".`

Since I am not a programmer neither a code designer, in order to make this form update some of the above selects and inputs that I added I had to make some "calculations on the fly".

I am pretty sure that this way is not a proper one but the form works! This has resulted when someone makes his/her selections or inputs and saves the form some of the DB fields get updated on the fly but some not.

Those fields that are calculated from other values are not correctly updated.

One needs to resubmit the form in order to get the correct results. The function that does the form submission is:

```
  function saveCompanyInformation() {
        if(validateCmpForm())
        return false;
        jQuery("#task").val('managecompany.save');
        jQuery("#selectedSubcategories").each(function(){ 
        jQuery("#selectedSubcategories option").attr("selected","selected"); 
        });
       var form = document.adminForm;
       form.submit();
  }
```

And the code that calls the above function is:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-dir-button ui-dir-button-green" onclick="saveCompanyInformation();">
     <span class="ui-button-text"><i class="dir-icon-edit"></i> <?php echo JText::_("Save Form")?></span>
</button>
```

Is there any way when someone submits the form there will be a "double form submission" so that those fields that are calculated on the fly to get the correct results? This should be transparent to the user.

There might be a set of instructions like:

1. Submit Form.
2. Reload page.
3. Submit Form Again.
4. Reload page.

That are executed with a single click of a button. Is that possible ? What would be the code to add ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not using a timeout or interval?

Comment: Thanks for replying... How can I do that? Will it resubmit the form? Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone give me some ideas?